# cant figure out proper syntax for sed using double quotes

Tags: bash, sed

I have an variable

`qsubFile="submitJob.sh"`

`echo $qsubFile` returns `submitJob.sh` without the double quotes.

Now, I want to find the line containing the string `qsubFile="someOtherFile.sh"` and replace it to `qsubFile="submitJob.sh"` in the file `"write.sh"`.

I tried using

`sed -i '/qsubFile=/c\qsubFile="'"$qsubFile"'"' write.sh`

`qsubFile=""`

I can't seem to get the proper syntax for this.

but it replaces it as

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need single quotes for `sed` to do this, there is no problem with the double quotes inside the single quotes:

```
sed -i 's/qsubFile="someOtherFile.sh"/qsubFile="submitJob.sh"/g' write.sh
```

If `"someOtherFile.sh"` isn't a fixed string in `write.sh` than use the follow to replace them all:

```
$ sed  -i 's/qsubFile="[^"]*"/qsubFile="submitJob.sh"/g' write.sh
```

Regex `"[^"]*"`:

```
"      # double quote
[^"]*  # Anything not a double quote
"      # double quote
```

Seems I misread the question the first time the correct quoting is to use the variable `$qsubFile` is, you missed the last `/`:

```
sed -i 's/qsubFile="[^"]*"/qsubFile="'"$qsubFile"'"/g' write.sh
```

Comment: you can also include double quotes by enclosing the whole thing in single quotes: `myvar='var="a string with spaces"'` ... or escaping the quotes `myvar="var=\"a string\""`

Answer (score 1):

You're somewhat on the right track if you need to use the shell variable though.

```
sed -i 's/qsubFile="someOtherFile.sh"/qsubFile="'"$qsubfile"'"/g' write.sh
```

or if you want to make sure you get the whole line

```
sed -i 's/^\(qsubFile=\).*$/\1"'"$qsubfile"'"/g' write.sh
```